# Show message when Tform2 is created?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I want to when Tform2 is created then show a message to user.
I use this code, but not work well.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   a:TForm2;
begin

if a=nil then
 begin
    a := TForm2.Create(Self);
    a.Show;
 end
 else
 begin
    showmessage('TForm2 is created');
 end;

end;
```

Comment: It doesnt work at all, yuo are checking Random(High(LongWord)) = 0. Also, logic with ShowMessage borked.

Comment: worm's cryptic comment refers to the fact that you are testing an uninitialised local variable and it's value is undefined. It's a shame that worm stated it in such an unhelpful manner.

Comment: Because it will motivate more people to answer you questions. :)

Comment: I would further add that you should be seeing a compiler warning like this: [DCC Warning] Unit1.pas(32): W1036 Variable 'a' might not have been initialized. You should always pay attention to the compiler warnings, and eliminate their cause.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because you declare `a` as a local variable. Each time you enter `TForm1.Button1Click` this variable will be brand new and uninitialized even though there might still be a Form2. That means that the check for nil won't even work.

You should either:

- Make `a` a global (like the Form2 global you get when you first create a form)
- Make `a` part of the declaration of Form1 (you main form?) or a datamodule of other class  that lives throughout your entire program.
- Don't use a variable at all, but check `Screen.Forms` to see if you got a Form2 in there.

[edit]

Like this:

```
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Check
  for i := 0 to Screen.FormCount - 1 do
  begin
    // Could use the 'is' operator too, but this checks the exact class instead
    // of descendants as well. And opposed to ClassNameIs, it will force you
    // to change the name here too if you decide to rename TForm2 to a more
    // useful name.
    if Screen.Forms[i].ClassType = TForm2 then
    begin
      ShowMessage('Form2 already exists');
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  // Create and show.
  TForm2.Create(Self).Show;
end;
```

Comment: Although the code sample works, may I suggest that you should never actually write code like this.  the other alternative, a global is much better.

Comment: I think the better option is a central application controller class that is used as a singleton that manages this stuff for you, but I think this might be a little too complex for the OP at this point. I think you should limit the use as globals as much as possible, but maybe you care to explain why you should 'never' write code like this and why a global is better?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible solution to your problem is to use a global variable instead of a local variable, or to make your variable a field (an instance variable) in your class.

A global variable of type TForm2 is initialized automatically to nil, but as you found out above, the local variable, which is located on something called the "stack" is not.

You should read and learn about local and global variable  scopes, and what the stack and the heap are.  These are general concepts that apply in almost any programming language that is not completely "managed". In other words, you have to think about this in C and C++ as well as in Pascal.

Such things (uninitialized local variables, and access violations) are something that some languages (C# and java) protect you from, to some degree.