# delphi using dbgrid to view a record on a detail page

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

I have a form with a dbgrid and a second form with dbedits. My form with the dbgrid has a double click event(code below is the event) the dbedits on the second form has a data source that is connected to the first form's CDS and when I compile and run the program and open the form with db grid I can double click any record and it is display in the dbedits on the second form, but if I close the forms and reopen the form the only record that will display in the second form dbedits is the first record in the table. I have to open and close CDS and that is not working.  what else would I need to do to correct this problem.

```
procedure TFRM_ADMIN.DBGrid1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
BEGIN
  frm_LEADDETAILADMINLEAD := tfrm_LEADDETAILADMINLEAD.Create(FRM_ADMIN);
  frm_LEADDETAILADMINLEAD.SHOW;   
END;
```

The site will not allow me to add the dmf text.  It is to large. I am using sqlconnection, sqlquery, data set provider, client data set, data source set up if this helps any.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't make any sense out of what you've written. Can you [edit] to make it more clear, and perhaps include some code that will demonstrate the problem you're having? Thanks.

Comment: The only code is in the dbgrid double click event that opens the detail form.  The problem begins when close the detail form and the form that contain the dbgrid and then you reopen the the form that contains the form that contains the dbgrid and select another record to view but only record that is loaded from the grid is the first record in the table.  no matter if you click the last record the only record that is loaded to detail is the first record in the table.  I hope this is clearer

Comment: You are obviously getting a state error somewhere in your project.  However perhaps you don't realise that there are numerous ways you could have implemented your dbgrid and detail forms, so readers here can hardly guess what your mistake might be.  I suggest you add to your q a) the code in your dbgrid dbl-click event and b) the text versions of the DFMs of both of your forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very wild quess, but I suspect the following at play:

- You use the public variables for the forms that the IDE automatically has added to each unit.
- You create `FRM_ADMIN` the way you create `frm_LEADDETAILADMINLEAD`, something like:

  ```
  FRM_ADMIN := TFRM_ADMIN.Create(MainForm);
  FRM_ADMIN.Show;
  ```
- You don't close this form, but hide it (the default close action of a form).
- The second time you create your second form, the designtime set `DataSet` property of the `DataSource` of your second form is automatically resolved to the ClientDataSet on the first instance of the first form.
- So in the second run you are editing the record that was selected in the first run.

Solution and recommendations:

- Destroy forms (set `Action := caFree`) in the `OnClose` event.
- Do not use the public variables, remove them. Keep you form reference in a separate private field, unique to each instance.
- Assign DataSource and/or DataSet properties at runtime explicitly.
- Use DataModules.

Further reading:

- [Binding a second instance of a form to a second instance of a data module?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19411637/757830)
- [Will there be any detrimental effects if I accidentally remove something from a forms uses list which a control is referencing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20619708/757830)
- [Separate DataSet instances using DataModules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6760750/757830).
- [Show message when Tform2 is created?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4773052/757830)

Comment: I close the form with a button click event "close"; I use the public varaible as you suspected. during the close of both forms I am closing the CDS.  I am totally lost as to why this is happening.   I am new to Delphi, I have a background sql, this is my first attempt at delphi.  I am not acustom to having to open and close the sql and  cds's. I am lost on the fact that everything work correctly until I close and reopen the form with dbgrid.